# c++ unique_ptr inside vector with inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm playing around with the different smart pointers and ran into a problem.

I have a `Environment` abstract class and a ground class which inherits `Environment`:

```
class Ground : public Environment
{
protected:
    std::string type;
    int damage;

public:
    Ground() : Environment()
    {
        this->type = "ground";
    }

    virtual void SetDamage(int _damage)
    {
        this->damage = _damage*5;
    }

    virtual std::string& GetType()
    {
        return this->type;
    }

    virtual int GetDamage()
    {
        return this->damage-10;
    }

    virtual ~Ground(){}
};
```

I also have a `Dirt` class which inherits the `Ground` class:

```
class Dirt : public Ground
{
public:
    Dirt() : Ground()
    {
        this->type = "dirt";
    }

    void SetDamage(int _damage)
    {
        this->damage = _damage*6;
    }

    int GetDamage()
    {
        return this->damage-20;
    }

    ~Dirt()
    {

    }


private:

};
```

Now if i want to use it inside a `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ground>> listGround;

std::unique_ptr<Ground> ground(new Ground());
listGround.push_back(ground);

std::unique_ptr<Dirt> dirt(new Dirt());
listGround.push_back(dirt); // FAIL

for (auto i = listGround.begin(); i != listGround.end(); i++)
{
    (*i)->SetDamage(80);
    std::cout << (*i)->GetType() << " " << (*i)->GetDamage() << std::endl;
}

listGround.empty();
```

I get a compile error saying that there is no user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion etc etc on the line that is marked FAIL in the above code.

If I use a `std::shared_ptr` everything works as intended. Same goes for raw pointers.

Why am I getting this error?

> error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(std::unique_ptr
>   &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to
>   'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&' 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=std::unique_ptr 1>          ] 1>          and 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=Dirt 1>          ] 1>          and 1>          [
>   1>              _Ty=Ground 1>          ] 1>          Reason: cannot
>   convert from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=Dirt 1>          ] 1>
>   and 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=Ground 1>          ] 1>
>   No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: Could you add the exact compiler error please?

Comment: You need to do `listGround.push_back(std::move(ground));`

Comment: thanks mate, got confused when the IDE just marked the new dirt wich an error instead of both lines when i tried to insert something into the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the thing in place:

```
listGround.emplace_back(new Dirt());
```

It's not a `shared_ptr`, yet you try to have ownership shared between `dirt` and `listGround.back()`

Comment: took me 5 minutes to understand ownership, was a little slow. Cleared up everything there buddy.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector::push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) requires the type passed to be copyable (or in C++11 movable) and `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable. That's what the error message is telling you that it is missing the corresponding conversion for moving. You can move a `std::unique_ptr` by using the `std::move` function which simply does the appropriate cast to the right r-reference type.

Comment: Actually, it requires only movable, not copyable. Critical difference since `unique_ptr` is movable.

Comment: I didn't see his error message was for the move version. My answer was previously correct for C++03, but I've updated it with move semantics for C++11.

Comment: Well, there wasn't exactly a `std::unique_ptr` before C++11. C++03 had the infamous `auto_ptr` and the ability to replace that with `std::unique_ptr` was a motivating factor for move semantics.

Comment: `std::tr1::unique_ptr` existed before C++11 and many people also used it from boost and some compilers exposed the tr1 `unique_ptr` in the `std` namespace prior to C++11.